# Two-way relations

Tags: entries, relations

I have a section 'people' which has several related entries such as 'sibling', 'spouse', 'offspring', etc. When creating a new 'person' the user has to set up these relationships. I understand that's it's possible to easily look up a persons relations in either direction as per http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations.

However, is it possible to reflect this in the CMS? So, when a person is related to another via 'spouse' it shows up for *both* people automatically? Currently, the user would have to do this manually.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible natively in Craft, but have look at the [Many-to-many plugin from Page 8](https://github.com/page-8/craft-manytomany). It might not be exactly what you're after, since it assumes that you have a relationship field in one channel, and the many-to-many field in another. But maybe you can figure out a way to adapt it to your case.

Comment: Yeah I tried this. As you say it deals with entries of different types so not useful to me as far as I can tell.

Comment: Spoke to the creator of this plugin and it's not possible currently.

Comment: @hamishtaplin But it will be shortly. I'll post an answer to this question when the feature is released.

Answer (score 2):

Iain's Introvert plugin shows the relationship on the child entry as well (reverse related entries).

http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/introvert

I haven't used it for Craft yet, but he wrote one for ExpressionEngine that worked well.